# Are you required to allocate memory for global struct pointers

Tags: c, struct, malloc

From what I know, if you create a global struct as follows:

```
something name;
int main(){
}
```

You are able to access every field of the struct `something`, but if I were to instead make it as:

```
something* name;
int main(){
}
```

Would this now be incorrect because I have to malloc the size of the struct?

Note, I haven't decided what the struct `something` contains, this is more of a general question.

Comment: To be able to dereference a pointer, it must point somewhere valid. In your case the pointer must point to a valid `something` object. If this object was created through `malloc` or any other way (for example by using another `something` object, and taking its address) doesn't matter.

Comment: With that said, *don't* use global variables. If you need multiple functions to access an object, pass (a pointer to) it as an argument instead. Then you could define the structure object as an actual structure object inside the `main` function and use the pointer-to operator `&` when passing it to your functions.

Comment: ...the fact that your pointer is global or local doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, pointer is just a variable that points to some address in memory. So after

```
something* name;
int main(){
}
```

all you have is a pointer. It should point to a place in memory, where struct
`something` exists, but for now its just garbage there (notice that pointer can point to random location and as long as you don't try to do something with it no error will occur). After calling malloc system will reserve space needed for `something` and return pointer you should assign to global variable.

Comment: global variables are initialized to `0` (`NULL` in case of pointers) in the absence of a definite initializer.

Answer (score 0):

> Would this now be incorrect because I have to malloc the size of the struct?

Well, it depends on how you are going to use it.

Code like:

```
something* name;
int main(){
}
```

is by it self perfectly valid C code.

You can for instance use it like:

```
something* name;
int main(){
    something x = {....};
    name = &x;             // Make name point to a "something" object
    ...
    name->some_member = ...;
    ...
}
```

or like

```
something* name;
int main(){
    something x = {....};
    name = malloc(sizeof *name);        // Make name point to a "something" object
    assert(name != NULL);
    ...
    name->some_member = ...;
    ...
}
```

But without an assignment to `name` like `name = ...` you can't dereference the pointer. In other words, this would be invalid

```
something* name;
int main(){
    ...
    name->some_member = ...;  // INVALID
    ...
}
```

because `name` doesn't point to a "something" object.

BTW:

Since `name` is global the code

```
something* name;
```

is the same as

```
something* name = NULL;
```

UNRELATED:

There are cases where global variables are good and useful but in most cases, it's best to avoid globals.